# in UriValidator.php line 21: Error Laravel ,Route with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

I get the following error when I use a function in ajax where I try to actualize every three seconds to know one count:

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: subpattern name is too long (maximum
>   32 characters) at offset 81

This is my ajax code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   function getRandValue(){
    var token = $("#token").val();
      $.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost/blog/public/Optica/UpdateClientes',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          $("#Empleados").html(data);
          console.log(data);        
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);  
        }

    });

      }
      setInterval(getRandValue, 3000);
});
```

The function `Route::get('Optica/{UpdateClientes}', 'HomeController@UpdateClientes');` is good because when this route is used, the number comes out and shows me as I put `cuandp json` but below the login auth gives me an error.

> in UriValidator.php line 21:
>
> preg_match(): Compilation failed: subpattern name is too long (maximum 32 characters) at offset 81